# Mysql table relations

Tags: mysql

I have read various topics regarding table relations and while i am building my database i am a bit confused on what should i do.
I have 3 type of registration on my site(artist, fan, companies). Each registered user gets a unique key and username and the appropriate type of user (ex. fan). I am trying to involve music genres to all types of registration but genres will also be added to uploaded music files. At the moment i am storing one music genre per track and user by an array list that is shown in a form. Then system is storing it to the appropriate field. But i want some users to have more than 1 genres stored.
Now what i have done is below:

```
Users table (total 14 columns)
ID | username | email | password | type | signup | lastlogin | etc.

Settings table (total 10 columns)
ID | username | description | banner | country | genres | avatar etc. 

Music table
ID | username | artist | title | maingenre | othergenre | cover | fileurl
```

By having in mind performance and let's assume that thousand of thousand users is registering...

1. Should i just add all settings column in the users table or it's ok to keep as i have them now? Settings can be updated by user while users table is updated by the system.
2. Should i split the user table according to users type? For example Artist table, fan table etc. that will store the appropriate registration and settings? Type of user needs to be in a column as is important for some functions of the site.
3. Regarding music table i was thinking to making a table for each genre that will store the uploads according to the genre specified by the user. Is this a good way of storing tracks to database or not? So when i want to call tracks of disco music i just use the disco music table.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quiet sure I understand everything completely how your table is correlated, or what exactly you want or plan to do, but here is one idea about how to store genres in your database. And to connect it with your Setting table

First create table Genres in which you will store all genres. That table could look like this

```
Table: Genres
ID | genres_name | description etc.
```

ID - will be primary key auto increment
genres_name - will hold the name of genre (blues, jazz, disco...)
description - this column i added just if you want to add something specific by every genre it's not necessary

Next step is to create table Settings_genres. This table will store relation between your Setting table and Genres table and will look like this

```
Table: Settings_genres
settings_id  | genres_id
```

So data in this table will look like this (for the setting ID 1 which will have 3 different Genres)

```
 settings_id | genres_id
------------------------
     1       |    2
------------------------
     1       |    4
------------------------
     1       |    5
------------------------
```

settings_id and genres_id will be primary key pair which means that you wont be able to store two identical pair int this table (You can have only one relation between one settings column and one genre column)

That is something called Many to many relationship and I'm sure that you can easily find more about that if you google it just a little.

When you want to pull data off from database which will show all settings and all genres you can do it with query like this

```
SELECT Settings.*, Genres.genres_name, Genres.description
FROM Settings
INNER JOIN Settings_Genres
ON Settings.ID = Settings_Genres.settings_id
INNER JOIN Genres
ON Settings_Genres.genres_id = Genres.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6a89/2) to see how it's look like.

When you want to pull data from settings table where that table is connected with specific genre you do that like this

```
SELECT Settings.*, Genres.genres_name, Genres.description
FROM Settings
INNER JOIN Settings_Genres
ON Settings.ID = Settings_Genres.settings_id
INNER JOIN Genres
ON Settings_Genres.genres_id = Genres.ID
WHERE Genres.genres_name = 'Rock'
ORDER BY ID;
```

This can also be achieved by this query which may be a little faster but let's not go into detail...

```
SELECT Settings.*, Genres.genres_name, Genres.description
FROM Settings
INNER JOIN Settings_Genres
ON Settings.ID = Settings_Genres.settings_id
INNER JOIN Genres
ON Settings_Genres.genres_id = Genres.ID
AND Genres.genres_name = 'Rock'
ORDER BY ID;
```

Here is [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6a89/5) for that...

So basically I suggest you to learn a little bit about relation between tables especially many to many relationship. And on than you will see how to improve your data table design.

Hope I help a little.

GL!

Comment: Thanks for the post. i will give it a try now.
Any thoughts about this -> 3. Regarding music table i was thinking to making a table for each genre that will store the uploads according to the genre specified by the user. Is this a good way of storing tracks to database or not instead of only 1 table? So when i want to call tracks of disco music i just use the disco music table.

Comment: @Billm I think you should do the pretty much the same thing as I connect your Settings table with Genre.. You will have table Uploads you use the table Genres (the same you use previous) and the table which will connect this two table uploads_genres which will contain pairs 1-5 1-7...

Comment: @Billm you're welcome... As I said before google a little about relation between table and database normalization there is a lot of material online. When you learn about database normalization you'll be able to design much more reliable and efficient database

Answer (score 0):

i think the way your table is, is okay. you dont have to split the table based on the type of users you have. but i think what you could use is font end technologies to allow users preform activities you want them, which is restricting them to only what you want them to do, they by controlling flow of information within the system. i hope that helps.